# Utility carts seem to all be only about 2 feet wide, is there a reason?

Tags: trailer

I wanted to get a flatbed type wagon or cart to tow behind a compact tractor which would be about 4' x 6'. However, it seems like all the regular utility wagons are only about 2' wide. For example, if you look at [the range of GorillaMade carts](https://gorillamade.com/carts/#products), a typical manufacturer, you can see that even the biggest wagons are only 3' wide.

Is there some reason why a 4' flatbed wagon is impractical that I don't see?

Comment: Size of a garden gate? Based on towing capacity?

Comment: Probably the tow weight limit of the towing tractor, people will want to overload a bigger cart(people usually not that smart).  If you pinky swear not to overload, then can get a light weight trailer made for cars, or make your own.

Comment: I meant the towing limit of the tractor, not the wagon/cart.  A few sheets of ply wood okay, a big square bale of hay is a no.

Comment: Gardening wagon have to fit true gate/doors, how ever there are others >>> Standard model includes 7 ft. by 4 ft. wide bed with 12 inch high removable side racks.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR **Doors**

Even though these carts are generally used outside, some are used inside (e.g., warehouses) or are stored inside a building of some sort. If you have a garage door or two doors side-by-side that provide a wide opening, great. But otherwise, the typical opening is between 2 and 3 feet. Even outside, gates in fences are often 3 feet wide.

Comment: A compact tractor is about 56"  to 60" wide, so the tractor itself would be wider than the wagon.

Comment: Correct. But if I were a manufacturer of yard equipment, I would see two different markets: narrow and wide. Narrow could be used by anyone, regardless of type of tractor, width of door, etc. Wide would *only* be for big tractors (to be strong enough to pull it) and to be left outside or for people with a shed with double-doors, or a big garage door, etc. In other words "wide customers can use narrow equipment, but narrow customers can't use wide equipment".